# Would it be faster to store data for a transposition table in a text file or an SQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm making a Connect 4 AI, and in order to increase its speed, I have saved previously evaluated positions in an SQLite3 database. (MySQL can be considered.) Take an example item that I would save:

`['       br     rbb    brbrb         rb          ',0.786]` <-- the string at the start is the board state, and the real is the evaluation for that position.

For my AI, it turns out to be slightly slower to fetch data rather than re-evaluate **if** I commit the saved data at the end (only if the evaluation function stays the same; if it changes and becomes more time-consuming to run, the speed of the data fetching may outweigh the evaluation). otherwise, the speed is perfectly fine. I want to be able to fetch the evaluation in the shortest time possible.

The only problem that I might have is with fetching the evaluation and **only** the evaluation. I am not very good with fetching and writing data to text files, and I'm not sure if isolating the evaluation will end up slowing down the process. What's the best way forward?

Comment: Faster for *what*? With a database you can read individual rows. With files you have to read everything and parse the contents to find what you want. Files make sense if you have millions of rows per file and a Spark cluster to partition and crunch the huge files

Comment: ["First make it work, then make it right, and, finally, make it fast."](https://wiki.c2.com/?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast is relative, and here you are talking about Input/Outputs (IOs)

IO speed depends on several factors, if you use a naive 'file' (CSV) then you are bound to the speed of your local file system. If you use a DB, you are bound to the connection to the DB.

The fastest you'll get is if you keep the data in memory rather than save it somewhere. You don't say how many rows you need to access, but a decent laptop computer has 16GB of memory these days, even with raw (uncompressed) data, that's 100's millions of rows of your type of data.

If you want speed, just keep the data in memory.

Now, your key to finding the 'evaluation' is a string. If you create a dictionary of the key and the value, as opposed to the array representation you have now, the lookup will be much faster as you don't need to scan the array to find the value; just lookup the key in the dict.

If you really have more rows than can fit into memory, then you might want to consider an in-memory key value store (sharded) rather than a DB. Something like a Redis cluster would be ideal for this use case. A key value store is like a dictionary you access over a connection like a DB. It can be sharded across many servers if size is an issue. If you know the key, retrieval is faster than a DB engine. (Although most DB engines will have cached data in memory too, it will need to go fetch data on disk at first)

Redis can be backed up to disk too; it just does so upon change of a number of keys (or time) that is configurable, so it is not spending its time trying to save to disk.